# How to get compile time errors in views using ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can we get compile time errors in views and view components in Mvc6?

In MVC 5, it was simple to edit the `.csproj` file. How do we do it now?

Answer (score 2):

## Answer for RC-1

1. Create the following `RazorPreCompilation` class:

```
namespace YourApp.Compiler.Preprocess
{
    public sealed class RazorPreCompilation : RazorPreCompileModule
    {
        protected override bool EnablePreCompilation(BeforeCompileContext context) => true;
    }
}
```

2. Places this class in {root}/Compiler/Preprocess.

[image]

3. Add a call to `AddPrecompiledRazorViews` in your `ConfigureServices` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other code ...
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddPrecompiledRazorViews(GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
    // ... other code ...
}
```

As noted in other answers, when views are precompiled you lose the ability to change them while the application is running. Additionally, it seems that sometimes you have to do a rebuild on your project (as opposed to just a build) in order for new code changes to take effect. For example, correcting a typo in a Razor method call may still trigger a compilation error until you rebuild the project.

#### Update on Directives

If you'd like to have this run with preprocess directives, wrap them around the `AddPrecompiledRazorViews` call like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other code ...
    var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvc()
    
#if !DEBUG
    mvcBuilder.AddPrecompiledRazorViews(GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
#endif

    // ... other code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add a class

```
public class RazorPreCompilation : RazorPreCompileModule
{
    public RazorPreCompilation(IServiceProvider provider) : base(provider)
    {
        this.GenerateSymbols = true;
    }
}
```

and Add `AddPrecompiledRazorViews` to your mvc setup in your startup class

see this [question](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3369)

Comment: Things changed in Beta 8. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre-compiled views by adding the following class to your project. However, doing this stops you from being able to edit the views at runtime. Therefore, I have added the `#if !DEBUG` pre-processor directive so that the views are only pre-compiled in release mode.

```
#if !DEBUG
namespace MvcBoilerplate.Compiler.Preprocess
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

    /// <summary>
    /// Enable pre-compilation of Razor views, so that errors in your .cshtml files are caught and displayed 
    /// in the Visual Studio errors window at compile time, rather than your sites users receiving a runtime 500 
    /// internal server error. Pre-compilation may reduce the time it takes to build and launch your project but will 
    /// cause the build time to increase. It will also stop edit and continue working for .cshtml files.
    /// </summary>
    public class RazorPreCompilation : RazorPreCompileModule
    {
    }
}
#endif
```

Secondly, in Startup.cs you need to actually use the pre-compiled views which you can do like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddPrecompiledRazorViews(GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
}
```

Pre-compiled views give quicker application startup performance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in beta 8 ? I have errors in views but not being picked up at build time.